# Incoherent performance test results

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have done performance testing with Apache JMeter. Sometimes, I received different results for the same test plan. How to handle this case? Applying statistical methods for results or network control or so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many things can impact the results. Its nearly impossible to achieve constant results even in low latency environment.
You can use some sort of average/rounding.